# Sprite Kit create a polygon from a Tiled object layer tmx?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, sprite-kit, tiled

I have this data from a Tiled tmx file

```
<objectgroup color="#00a9ff" name="poly" width="500" height="24">
<properties>
<property name="poly" value="1"/>
</properties>
<object name="poly" x="305" y="472">
<properties>
<property name="value" value="1"/>
</properties>

<polygon points="109,6 395,71 -142,69"/>
</object>
</objectgroup>
</map>
```

I want to make CGPoints from the polygon points but when I make an NSArray from polygon points
I dont get 3 CGPoints or the items in the array, I get all the values together as a single item in the array.

How can I separate  polygon points="109,6 395,71 -142,69"  into 3 CGPoints?

thank you for the help :D

Comment: You can look it up in or use this reader: https://github.com/KoboldKit/KoboldKit/blob/master/KoboldKit/KoboldKitFree/Framework/TilemapModel/TMX/KKTMXReader.m

Comment: or you can wait for ios 8 which comes with its own editor and you wont have to deal with the tmx reading headache!